# Connecting an early 2015 MacBook Pro Retina to an LG 27UK850-W

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

Wondering how to connect my early 2015 13 inch MacBook Pro with the Retina Display to my new LG 27UK850-W 4K monitor. I have read several methods but want to know the best one, especially whether it's possibly to just connect them through one HDMI 2.0 cable and get 4K (upscaled) video and normal audio. Cannot test it out since I have just ordered the monitor. 
Also: say I would watch a 4K video, which would of course be displayed as 2560x1600 by the Retina display. Would the 4K monitor then upscale this from the Mac's output to 4K or would it show the true 4K from the video output?

Comment: Normally, you determine this *before* making a purchase.   But basically, you can use an HDMI cable or a DisplayPort cable.  Which is better is entirely up to you, but personally I prefer DisplayPort.

Comment: I understand it sounds stupid but I made the purchase to use the monitor together with my PS4 PRO and thus this wasn't a priority. Plus, I knew it was going to be possible, just not how easily. Apparently it is easy, thank you very much. Why do you prefer DisplayPort?

Comment: I prefer DisplayPort because HDMI has clock sync issues especially with audio where it will just drop and you have to disconnect/reconnect to get it working again.  My Roku stick also has the problem....when the audio drops, I have to cycle inputs to regain it.